# creating raw offline transaction alt coin

Tags: go-ethereum

Is it possible to create a raw offline transaction using geth for alt-coins?  I'm trying to write some sample code to automatically do a shapeshift transaction and want to convert, say, between GNT and RLC.  Is there any sample code for that?

Also, does the blockchain need to be synced to do this?